# Use GroupActivities with Objective-C Classes?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, ios15

So the new SharePlay on iOS 15 works by utilizing GroupActivities which are only available in Swift. My existing app has a fairly extensive bit of code for viewing videos, but that code is all Objective-C.

If I want to get SharePlay to work with this app, am I going to have to convert all that to Swift, or is it possible to pass the AVPlayer stuff back and forth?

Can GroupActivity be in its own class and receive the data from the Objective-C file that parses the video file in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `playbackCoordinator` of the `AVPlayer` class, you'll have to call the `coordinateWithSession()` via Swift.
This doesn't mean you have to convert all of your existing classes to Swift, what about creating a Swift extension of your Objective-C class for the coordination ?

Comment: Ok. Can you point me in direction of some reading for how to do that? I've never done anything with Swift before.

Comment: Well, I think this should help you integrating your swift file in your project
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-and-objective-c-interoperability-2add8e6d6887

Comment: So, I finally got around to working on this again (honestly forgot I asked this question). I have set up the swift extension and bridging-header as shown in the link you sent. My question is, how do I go about implementing the Swift code for GroupActivities? Is it something that I can create a method for inside of the Obj-C and then in the swift file do the code required for setting up SharePlay?